# Smart table SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I want to using smart table but failed. below xml code:

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="com.taspen.acb.modules.Dosir.FileUpload"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:smartTable="sap.ui.comp.smarttable"
    class="viewPadding">
    <l:VerticalLayout>

              <smartTable:SmartTable entitySet="TableList"
                          smartFilterId="smartFilterBar" tableType="Table" useExportToExcel="true"
                          useVariantManagement="false" useTablePersonalisation="true" header="Line Items"
                          showRowCount="true" persistencyKey="SmartTableAnalytical_Explored"
                          enableAutoBinding="true" />           

    </l:VerticalLayout>
</mvc:View>
```

Error show : Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/comp/smarttable/SmartTable.js' from resources/sap/ui/comp/smarttable/SmartTable.js: 404 - Not Found

I using sap-ui-core.js version 2.3.0. I want using smart table because I want to selection show column table. (my column table too many).

Thank you

Regards,
Bobby

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly import the comp library in your index.html file

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    [...]
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ui.comp"
    [...]
</script>
```